# Convert lambda expression to anonymous method?

Tags: c#, lambda, anonymous-methods

I am having a hard time understanding lambda expression. From my understanding lambda expression is a convenient(less codes) was of represting anonymous method. I understand anonymous method. In the below codes sample how to change the lambda expression to anonymous method?

```
public class CustomersController : Controller {
    // GET: Customers
    public ViewResult Index() {
        var customers = GetCustomer();
        return View(customers);
    }
    public ActionResult Details(int id) {
        var customers = GetCustomer().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);   
        if (customers == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        return View(customers);
    }
    private IEnumerable<Customers> GetCustomer() {
        return new List<Customers> {
            new Customers { Id = 1, Name="John Smith"},
            new Customers { Id = 2, Name = "Mary Smith"}   
        };   
    }    
}
```

Comment: Lambda expressions can be converted to [expression trees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx) while anonymous methods cannot. Therefore, when dealing with frameworks/libraries that require expression trees, e.g. entity framework, you have to use lambda expressions.

Answer (score 3):

One way to bridge from the syntax of lambdas to the syntax of anonymous methods is to transform it from its simplest form to a more complex form. Hence, your expression would become

```
var customers = GetCustomer().SingleOrDefault(c => {
    return c.Id == id;
});
```

Now that the body consists of a proper statement and is inside a pair of curly braces, we can complete the transformation to anonymous method syntax:

```
var customers = GetCustomer().SingleOrDefault(delegate (Customer c) {
    return c.Id == id;
});
```

You can see that lambda syntax is a simplification of a general anonymous delegate, with `delegate (Customer c)` reduced to `c =>` with an inferred type, no curly braces, and the expression from the `return` statement serving as the body.

Answer (score 0):

```
var customers = GetCustomer().SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
```

Let's break out that line a little bit.  GetCustomer returns an `IEnumerable<Customer>`, so `SingleOrDefault` is declared on `System.Linq.Enumerable`.

```
Func<Customer, bool> criteria = c => c.Id = id;
var customers = Enumerable.SingleOrDefault(GetCustomers(), criteria);
```

In this code, the compiler transforms the lambda expresion into an anonymous method.  `criteria` is a local variable which references the anonymous method.

---

Now change GetCustomers to return `IQueryable<Customer>`, so that `SingleOrDefault` is defined on `System.Linq.Queryable`.

```
Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> criteria = c => c.Id = id;
var customers = Queryable.SingleOrDefault(GetCustomers(), criteria);
```

In this code, the compiler transforms the lambda expresion into an expression tree.  `criteria` is a local variable which references the expression tree.  The implementation of the `IQueryable<Customer>` from `GetCustomers` may compile the expression tree into a locally executing .net method, or it may translate the expression into SQL and send it to a database, or something else.  It's up to the runtime implementation of the `IQueryable<Customer>`.